# How to Pass Parameter from Azure Pipeline to Python Script?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to create an user Input for some Azure DevOps pipeline variable and get those variable in the Python script.

Below is my yml file

```
parameters:
- name: Action123
  displayName: 'Select Action'
  type: string
  default: 'enable'
  values:
  - 'enable'
  - 'disable'

trigger: none
stages:
- stage: Create
  pool: 
   name: sdasdasd
   demands:
    - agent.name -equals sdasdasd
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - script: echo Building!
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          export Action123=$(Action123)
          python job/job-action.py

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo 'Action123 Taken =========>>>' + $(Action123)
      displayName: Summary for Dev Action Utility
```

And here is my python script

```
import requests
import json
import os


Action123 = os.getenv('Action123')

print("Action123 ===========>>> " + Action123) #This is not getting printed
```

I am not sure where I am getting it wrong, tried multiple time but the Variable **Action123**  Is Coming as empty.

Strange thing is if I do

```
print(os.environ)
```

it's giving

```
{'otherdields & value,
 'Action123': 'enable', 
 'otherdields & value}
```

Can you please correct me where its getting wrong

Thanks

Comment: you could introduce a delay using time.sleep() to give it some time to be set. just for debuging

Comment: @OyinladeDemola :- Thanks for the response, Its still the same with `time.sleep()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the DevOps variable value to python script by `os.getenv()` is correct.

Since you are using self-hosted agent pool, and Variable Action123 gets empty, you can define it explictly in the yaml, to make sure the value is given.

```
parameters:
- name: Action123
  displayName: 'Select Action'
  type: string
  default: 'enable'
  values:
  - 'enable'
  - 'disable'

variables:
  - name: Action123              # define the variable to make sure it has the value.
    value: ${{ parameters.Action123 }}

trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Create
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - script: echo Building!
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          export Action123=$(Action123)
          python job/job-action.py

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo 'Action123 Taken =========>>>' + $(Action123)
      displayName: Summary for Dev Action Utility
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: Glad to know it helps! Happy coding!